# IIS 7.0-7.5 IP address rebinding when adding IP's through netsh

Tags: iis, ssl

I have about 50 or so websites that are all bound to the "unassigned" IP address binding in IIS, which means they'll respond to any IP address assigned to that server. Their DNS A records point to a specific one, so it works. I now want to bind an SSL certificate to a specific site, but I have no way to target a specific IP address, since they aren't listed in the IP address dropdown list.

Google led me to this support doc: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954874

It makes sense, but my question is.. if I add all the IP addresses assigned to that server with netsh, then restart those services.. does the "unassigned" option go away? will all those sites automatically become unbound, or will they stay "unassigned" and respond to everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went ahead and did it anyway, it did indeed break all the sites, I had to add `0.0.0.0` to the IP list to have the "unassigned" option work again.

Hope this helps someone in the future